# AngularJs navbar routing directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a two-level navbar that works quite well.

- Top level displays main menu.
- Second level displays menu for any subcontent.  This is hidden when no sub items are found.

  ```
  <div id="nav-wrap">
    <nav id="nav" class="site-nav" data-ng-class="{'sub-nav': hasSubRoutes()}">
      <div class="row">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="route in routes"><a href="#{{route.url}}" title="{{ route.config.title }}" data-ng-class="{'active': isCurrentRoute(route)}">{{route.config.title}}</a>
            <ul data-ng-class="{'active': isCurrentRoute(route)}">
              <li ng-repeat="subItem in route.subItems" data-ng-class="{'ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active': isCurrentSubRoute(subItem)}"><a href="#{{subItem.url}}" title="{{subItem.config.title}}"><span>{{subItem.config.title}}</span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  ```

And this is what I'm replacing the above with:

```
<my-navbar />
```

And here is the code for everything else

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var newRoutes = {
  routes:
  [
    { "url": "/layout", "config": { "title": "Layout", "templateUrl": "pageContent/layout.html" } },
    { "url": "/commandments", "config": { "title": "Commandments", "templateUrl": "pageContent/commandments.html" } },
    { "url": "/release", "config": { "title": "Release Notes", "templateUrl": "pageContent/release.html" } },
    { "url": "/resources", "config": { "title": "Resources", "templateUrl": "pageContent/resources.html" } },
    {
      "url": "/whatever", "redirectTo": "/whatever/resources1", "config": { "title": "Whatever" },
      "subItems":
      [
        { "url": "/whatever/resources1", "config": { "title": "Resources", "templateUrl": "pageContent/resources.html" } },
        { "url": "/whatever/release1", "config": { "title": "Release", "templateUrl": "pageContent/release.html" } }
      ]
    }
  ],
  otherwise: "/layout"
};

angular.module("themeApp", ["ngRoute"])
    .constant("routes", newRoutes.routes)
    .constant("otherwise", newRoutes.otherwise)
    .config(function ($routeProvider, routes, otherwise) {

        routes.forEach(function (r) {
            if (r.redirectTo) {
                $routeProvider.when(r.url, {
                    redirectTo: r.redirectTo
                });
            }
            if (r.subItems) {
                r.subItems.forEach(function (sr) {
                    $routeProvider.when(sr.url, sr.config);
                });
            } else {
                $routeProvider.when(r.url, r.config);
            }
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: otherwise });

    })
    .controller("themeController", ["$scope", "$location", "routes", function ($scope, $location, routes) {

        //Public Parameters
        $scope.routes = routes;

    }])

    .directive("myNavbar", [function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: '<div id="nav-wrap"><nav id="nav" class="site-nav" data-ng-class="{\'sub-nav\': hasSubRoutes()}"><div class="row"><ul><li ng-repeat="route in routes"><a href="#{{route.url}}" title="{{ route.config.title }}" data-ng-class="{\'active\': isCurrentRoute(route)}">{{route.config.title}}</a><ul data-ng-class="{\'active\': isCurrentRoute(route)}"><li ng-repeat="subItem in route.subItems" data-ng-class="{\'ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active\': isCurrentSubRoute(subItem)}"><a href="#{{subItem.url}}" title="{{subItem.config.title}}"><span>{{subItem.config.title}}</span></a></li></ul></li></ul></div></nav></div>',
            replace: true,
            controller: function ($scope, $location) {

                //COPIED FROM themeController
                //Public Methods
                $scope.isCurrentRoute = isCurrentRoute;
                $scope.isCurrentSubRoute = isCurrentSubRoute;
                $scope.hasSubRoutes = hasSubRoutes;

                //Private Variables
                var hasSubItems;

                //Private Methods
                function hasSubRoutes() {
                    return hasSubItems;
                }

                function isCurrentRoute(route) {
                    var current = getCurrent(route);

                    hasSubItems = false;
                    if (current) {
                        hasSubItems = route.subItems && route.subItems.length > 0;
                    }
                    return current;
                }

                function isCurrentSubRoute(route) {
                    return getCurrent(route);
                }

                function getCurrent(route) {
                    var path = route.url;
                    return $location.path().substr(0, path.length) === path;
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
  }())
```

Here's the problem:

1. Right now, the menu bar shows up and I can click the menu commands, the code to manipulate the menu tabs works great!  However, I get no content.
2. When I restore the HTML (use the 'nav-wrap' HTML from above, and copy the javascript from the directive controller into the themeController and remove '<my-navbar>'), it works perfectly.  The menu works and I get the content.

Thanks,
Duane

Answer (score 1):

While I didn't get any JavaScript errors, I did get a warning that I finally paid attention to.

The browser didn't like my self-closing <my-navbar />, though I swear I've done that before with other directives...but I could be wrong.

Once I changed it to:

```
<my-navbar></my-navbar>
```

everything worked.

Thank you Khanh for working with me!!!!

Comment: I think you should use isolated scope to make the component reusable.

Comment: Hi Khanh, I implemented your recommended changes, but the problem had to do with my self-closing navbar - it didn't like that.  If I'd been able to create a plunk, I'm sure you would have pointed that out a lot sooner than it took me to find it.  I really do appreciate your taking the time to help me.  :-)